# Adding Metronic 5 components to ASPNET.Zero template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I need some advice on what the best practice is in adding Metronic 5.0 components into my ASP.NET zero template. I was expecting that Metronic 5 would include directives for Angular 2 but it is not the case and all components are set to a field via JQuery yet. For example how would I be able to include the [Metroic 5 slider](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=components/forms/widgets/nouislider&demo=default) into my project? I have noticed that there is a PrimeNg slider directive in the project and once I included it into my main.module i can simply using its directive in my code. But how can I use Metronic ones? I can't find any angular directive for Metronic in the downloaded package! there are just some demo pages which all are using Javascript to bind html elements to components. I have not found the core javascripts code for the Metronic elements yet though!

I think it would be very helpful to have a tutorial on how to add extra metronic components into the template.